# Sharing remote folder in subdir

Tags: windows, alias, net-use

I want to use a remote shared folder use in a subdirectory.
For example the share \somePC\folder => x:\folder\somePCsRemoteFolder

is there an easy way to do this ?

endo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a symlink:

```
mklink /d x:\folder\somePCsRemoteFolder \\somePC\folder
```

Under Linux, `alias` would *not* work this way.

Comment: you're right with alias

Comment: just lovely, thx